# HTML5 VIDEO is not playing on iphones and ios devices ,can you please review my code and suggest issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ios, html5-video

so i am creating a website which has video background for hero section but i found out video isnt playing in iphone. i used video tag for creating the same .I found some solutions on the stackover which isnt working either. ill paste the code.

```
        <div class="video-container">
            <video class="video-bg" autoplay="autoplay" loop muted playsinline>
                <source src="./Media/Blue Liquid Art Design Gallery Intro Video.mp4" type="video/webm"
                    alt="HTML5 background video">
            </video>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u change the video type to video/mp4?

```
    <div class="video-container">
        <video class="video-bg" autoplay="autoplay" loop muted playsinline>
            <source src="./Media/Blue Liquid Art Design Gallery Intro Video.mp4" type="video/mp4"
                alt="HTML5 background video">
        </video>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks you so much mecit i was struggling with this. thanks a lot man